# How to linearize this if-then constraint? $x \geq 1\Rightarrow y=0$ otherwise use $y$ as it is.

Tags: linear-programming, integer-programming, linearization

If $x \geq 1$ then force $y=0$; otherwise $y$ should take its value, where $x$ and $y$ are non-negative integer decision variables. The variables $x$ and $y$ are calculated in other constraints. I tried the following by introducing a binary variable $z$, but it didn't work:

$x \geq 1-M(1-z)$

$y \leq M(1-z)$

Answer (score 1):

Equivalently, you want to enforce $x>0 \implies y \le 0$.  Suppose $M_x$ is an upper bound on $x$ and $M_y$ is an upper bound on $y$.  Introduce binary variable $z$ and impose linear constraints
\begin{align}
x &\le M_x z \tag1\label1 \\
y &\le M_y(1-z) \tag2\label2
\end{align}
Constraint \eqref{1} enforces $x > 0 \implies z = 1$.
Constraint \eqref{2} enforces $z = 1 \implies y \le 0$.

Comment: Thanks for the response. When $x>0$, and if I calculate the value of $y$ manually from other constraint, it's negative. And it violates the condition that $y$ is non-negative, making the problem infeasible.

Comment: Did you also explicitly impose $x \ge 0$ and $y \ge 0$?  You said *non-negative*, so I didn't mention these lower bounds in my answer.

Comment: Yes, I did impose.

Comment: What values of $M_x$ and $M_y$ did you use, and what values of $x$, $y$, and $z$ did the solver return?